# Validate the first or last consecutive and equal numbers

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to validate that the first two digits of a number which are not consecutive or equal.
This is for a ReactJS project, using a conditional "for" and "if" to achieve the validation.

I have this code:

```
for (let i = 0; i < arrayPassword.length - 1; i++) 
{
    const actual = parseInt(arrayPassword[i])
    const next = parseInt(arrayPassword[i + 1])

    //validate consecutive and equal numbers
    let isConsecutive = actual + 1 === next || actual === next ? true : false;

    if (isConsecutive) {
      callback(`consecutive and equal numbers are not allow.`);
    } else {
      callback();
    }
}
```

At this moment I can validate the full expression when I have a 4 digits consecutive or equal, for example:

```
(1111, 2222, 3333, 1234, 2345, 6789, ...)
```

and it's ok, but the problem appears when the first two digits are equal or consecutive, for example:

```
(1147, 2293, 3360, 1244, 6750, 8952, ...)
```

I hope that through a condition the numbers like the previous examples do not enter the conditional If.
I appreciate the interest in helping me.

Comment: Just fyi, `let isConsecutive = actual + 1 === next || actual === next ? true : false;` is redundant. You can directly do `let isConsecutive = actual + 1 === next || actual === next;`

Comment: Is it *specifically* the first two digits with the restrictions? Is 4077 valid?

Comment: if I evaluate the number 4077 does not enter in the If conditional and it´s ok, but if I evaluate the number 4470, it's enter in the If conditional and this is what I do not want to happen. Thanks for your appreciation.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question. To be clear, the only numbers that *should not* be allowed are those where all four digits are consecutive or equal (1111, 2345), and smaller runs *should be, but are currently not* allowed (1147, 1244). Correct? (Use "@AuxTaco" in your reply so it shows up in my inbox.)

Comment: @AuxTaco it´s correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to know that a number is invalid before looking at all its digits, but your code calls the callback within the loop, after looking at only two. In fact, the callback is called *three times*, once on each iteration. To fix it, keep track of each validity check in a separate variable, and only call the callback after the loop completes:

```
let equalSoFar = true;
let consecutiveSoFar = true;

for (let i = 0; i < arrayPassword.length - 1; i++) {
  const actual = parseInt(arrayPassword[i])
  const next = parseInt(arrayPassword[i + 1])

  // validate equal numbers
  // "equalSoFar &&" because after a nonequal digit is encountered, equalSoFar MUST be false
  equalSoFar = equalSoFar && actual === next;

  // validate consecutive numbers
  // "consecutiveSoFar &&": same logic
  consecutiveSoFar = consecutiveSoFar && actual + 1 === next;
}

if (equalSoFar || consecutiveSoFar) {
  callback(`consecutive and equal numbers are not allowed.`);
} else {
  callback();
}
```

You can also break each validity check into its own function and examine the number array with [`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every). A number array has all equal digits if each of its digits is equal to the first one. It has all consecutive digits if each digit is equal to the first one plus its index in the array.

```js
function allSameDigit(array) {
  return array.every(digit => digit === array[0]);
}

function allConsecutiveDigits(array) {
  return array.every((digit, index) => +digit === +array[0] + index);
}

function isValid(array) {
  return !allSameDigit(array) && !allConsecutiveDigits(array);
}



const testValues = [1111, 2222, 3333, 1234, 2345, 6789, 1147, 2293, 3360, 1244, 6750, 8952]
  .map(num => num.toString().split(''));
for (let arr of testValues)
  console.log(`${arr.join('')}: ${isValid(arr) ? 'valid' : 'invalid'}`);
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this simple function do what you need - checks if any two adjacent numbers in a password array are equal or consecutive

```
function neighboursAreEqual(arrayPassword) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayPassword.length - 1; i++) {
        const current = parseInt(arrayPassword[i]);
        const next = parseInt(arrayPassword[i + 1]);
        if (current === next || Math.abs(current - next) === 1) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//    to test how it works
console.log(neighboursAreEqual([]))    //    false (no symbols to compare)
console.log(neighboursAreEqual(['1']))    //    false (no neighboring symbol)
console.log(neighboursAreEqual(['1', '2']))    //    true (consecutive)
console.log(neighboursAreEqual(['1', '3']))    //    false
console.log(neighboursAreEqual(['2', '2']))    //    true(equal)
console.log(neighboursAreEqual(['0', '2', '4']))    //    false
console.log(neighboursAreEqual(['0', '2', '3']))    //    true (consecutive)
console.log(neighboursAreEqual(['0', '8', '2', '2']))    //    true  (consecutive)
```

If you need to compare only first two symbols in array (though I don't know the reason for such requirement) the function becomes even easier - you won't even need `for` there...

Comment: Thank you very much for your appreciation, but perhaps I have not given you the right question. The validation for the set of the 4 digits is fine, but I also want that when evaluating the set of the 4 digits do not interpret that the first two digits are consecutive or equal to be followed by two non-consecutive and unequal numbers. Simply the condition that they be consecutive and equal applies to the number consisting of 4 digits.

Comment: Your description is a bit unclear indeed. Is it correct to say that your validation rule should only look into first two digits? Meaning that passwords like: 1175, 1275, 4596 are all invalid (first two digits are equal or consecutive) but passwords like 3511, 5312, 3551, 3125 are valid (though they have pairs of equal or consecutive digits these digits are not at the beginning of a password)? Yet do you need to check “not being consecutive” rule only in accendign order or in descending too? Simply speaking are passwords like 2135 or 9835 valid?